# Single marker stuck beneath polygon in Fusion Tables layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

So this strikes me as, perhaps, a really obscure bug.

I'm working on a map for the upcoming Quebec election. You can see it [here](http://demarchy.ca/qc2012)

So I built a fusion table with all the riding polygons, and I've begun adding points for ridings of interest. They all work fine - except one. If you zoom in on the area around Montreal (Laval, specifically) there's one blue dot that is stuck behind a red polygon and it simply isn't clickable.

I've tried screwing around with the zindex for all the markers, but haven't had much luck. Here's what I'm doing:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: 
    {
        select: 'Geocodable address',
        from: '4722124'
    },
    styles: 
    [
        {
            markeroptions: { zindex: 1, }
        }, 
        {
            polygonOptions: { zindex: 2, }
        }
    ]
});

layer.setMap(map);
```

Beyond that, I'm not entirely sure what to do. The rest of the markers work fine.

Currently, I'm just plugging the points manually into the fusion table. Should I drop them using CSS and edit the zindex that way? (Assuming this is just a glitch and there's no other solution.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to force markers to be on top is to put them in a separate layer

```
var layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'Geography',
    where: "Marker does not contain '_'",
    from: '4749709' // '4722124'
 }});
layer1.setMap(map);
var layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'Geography',
    where: "Marker contains '_'",
    from: '4749709' // '4722124'
 }});
layer2.setMap(map);
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/demarchy_ca_qc2012a.html)

That has the disadvantage of potentially displaying two infowindows at the same time.  A work around for that is to manage the infowindow yourself.

[Working example with single infowindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/demarchy_ca_qc2012b.html)

Comment: Your first code worked, insofar as it registered on the map and it set everything as two layers. Unfortunately, that damned marker was still stuck under the overlay.

I tried the second and it refused to work. I initially just plugged in the changes, and the map didn't initialize. Then I copy and pasted your code - nothing. Cleared my cache repeatedly and just couldn't get the thing to register, no matter how many times I edited it.

I think I'll just create this marker manually.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Does the live version of my examples work, but your copy doesn't (might be a caching issue)?  For me in firefox (and in Chrome at home) the marker layer was on top of the polygon layer.  Just noticed a typo in the code I posted, which I fixed in the live version (and just edited the answer to fix).

Comment: I'm on Chrome. Your live versions (both) work perfectly, but neither work for me (yet I notice differences in how the polygons look, as per how they should with the new layer rules.)

I should note that this weird glitch also happens when I map my fusion table in the FT UI. It appears to be *only* this polygon, too. When I put the marker over another polygon, it doesn't happen. I've tried deleting the row that contains that polygon and re-adding it - no dice. Ditto for the marker.

I'm also trying it on two different computers (one Windows, one Linux. One Chrome, the other Chromium.)

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for a long time myself. I tried creating the markers and polygons in a different order (eg polygon first, marker second, and visa versa) but have found no way to control which item is on top of another.

My work-around was to export the fusion table to a KML file, and then manually reorganize the order of items in the file. The higher a placemark appears in the KML file, the closer to the top it will be in the item order on the map. That is -- put your markers first, and polygons second, and then you will be able to click on the markers.

Hope this helps!

Question to FUSION team -- surely you can write this logic into the Fusion Tables code?